# Cypress 400 XHR error when clicking to send a request

Tags: automated-tests, cypress, end-to-end

I've been working with cypress for one day now. I have a button that will refresh the page once you click on it and some tests after that still go through.

clicking on this button will throw a 400 error. ( post request )

I'm able to click other buttons on the page and can also manually do it within the browser in a new tab. but once the test automates it, it will fail.

I read a few cases:
[#1951](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1951)
[#2001](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2001)

but none seem to be able to solve this issue.

*index.js*

```
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  on('before:browser:launch', (browser, launchOptions) => {
    if (browser.name === 'chrome') {
      launchOptions.args.push('--disable-site-isolation-trials');
      launchOptions.args.push('--incognito')
      return launchOptions
    }
  })
}
```

*test.js*

```
context('Checkout Purchase', () => {
    describe('Checkout Form', () => {
        it('Tests Promo Codes', () => {
            cy.wait(2000);
            cy.get('#promoCode')
            .type('bw-nw-testing')
            .should('have.value', 'bw-nw-testing')
            cy.get('#applyPromoCodeButton')
              .click()
              .wait(2000)
        })
        })
})
```

*cypress.json*

```
{
  "projectId": "lkj8fdj",
  "chromeWebSecurity": false,
  "baseUrl": "http://localhost:3000"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

HTTP 400 status code stands for [Bad-Request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). (i.e. the request sent to the API's endpoint is not the one that the API is expecting).
If said HTTP request is being sent from your application, and not directly from Cypress, probably the application code for making the request is somewhat wrong.

Check the network tab on your browser, and try to manually replicate the request being sent to your external(?) API.

note: Usually during tests, it's common practice to stub (mock) the responses from external entities, but first you got to make sure that the outgoing request is right in the first place. Otherwise you could be masking a bug in the application.

Comment: *updated* im able to send a request manually in the same browser when opening a new tab. As well as normally in my own browser. whenever its automated is when it fails

Comment: @Pwntastic if you use Cypress to open the browser and load the site, what happens when you try to carry out the steps manually within that browser?

Comment: If i do everything manually it all works fine. wether inside the cypress browser or not. @natn2323

Comment: Hello,

i am facing the exact same issue.
The links are returning 404 in CI but in my local it is passing.
@Pwntastic how have you resolved it pls.
thanks

Comment: @ZombiePie Hey there, I dont remember how I ended up solving this issue. It looks like i had an answer but deleted it. I undeleted it for you below to check out. I'm not sure if it will do much help though.

Answer (score 0):

I found a decent answer why. If anybody has any other insight I'd love to hear.

Resource: [superdomain](https://www.w3resource.com/cypress/web-security.php) Here are some examples of test cases that will throw an error due to  limitations:

- .click() an  with an href to another superdomain.
- .submit() a  that causes your web server to redirect to you another superdomain.
- Issue a JavaScript redirect in your application, such as window.location.href = '...', to another superdomain.